# Working with two requests for auth with rxjava

Tags: android, retrofit, rx-java2

I have a project with login page. On this page, after user clicks on "sign in", I need to send request to checkUserName (check if we have such user and he can login) and only then to auth.

In the code I have this:

Interface:

```
@POST("endpoint")
Flowable<AccountResponse> auth(@Body AuthRequestBody authRequestBody);

@POST("endpoint")
Flowable<CheckUsernameResponse> checkUserName(@Body CheckUserNameRequest checkUserNameRequest);
```

RestService:

```
public Flowable<AccountResponse> auth(String login, String password) {
    return api.auth(new AuthRequestBody(login, password)).compose(handleError());
}

public Flowable<CheckUsernameResponse> checkUserName(String login) {
    return api.checkUserName(new CheckUserNameRequest(login)).compose(handleError());
}
```

And Rx:

```
public Flowable<AccountResponse> auth(String login, String password) {
    return checkUsername(login).flatMap(checkUsernameResponse -> restService.auth(login, password))
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .doOnNext(loginResponse -> {
                tokenManager.saveToken(loginResponse.getToken());
            });
}

public Flowable<CheckUsernameResponse> checkUsername(String login) {
    return restService.checkUserName(login)
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io());
}
```

How I can check in Rx, if first query is ok? (checkUsername). I mean, that API didn't returned error msg, UserId is ok and isAccessGranted is true and only then send a second request to auth?

Answer (score 0):

Inside of `flatMap`, you are free to do any checking/validation you want before you return a new `Flowable` or emit an error. So, omitting Scheduler considerations for brevity, you might have:

```
public Flowable<AccountResponse> auth(String login, String password) {
        return checkUsername(login)
            .flatMap(checkUsernameResponse -> {
                // do whatever checking you want to do here, e.g.:
                if (!checkUsernameResponse.isUsernameOk()) {
                    throw new RuntimeException("Access not granted."));
                }
                // First call succeeded, proceed to the second one:
                return restService.auth(login, password);
            })
            .doOnNext(loginResponse -> {
                tokenManager.saveToken(loginResponse.getToken());
            });
        }
```